# Firebird overgrow database file

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Is there a way to check why my database is increasing its size so fast? I had a growth of 30GB in less than a week and all my process and procedures are so slow now, with the same amount of transactions as usual.

Or is there a way to check the size of the table?

Comment: This is probably a question that is better to ask on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support)

Comment: Also, what exact version of Firebird are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table that you suspect might be growing you can run the following command from the command line.

```
gstat <DATABASE NAME|ALIAS> -t <TABLE_NAME>
```

Additional information on gstat can be found here. https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gstat/firebird-gstat.html

You can have this command run on a schedule and save the results so you can see what is happening over time. Although, this command might take a while to run based on the size of the table.

Comment: This won't include things like size of blobs.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, I didn't know that. In my situation, we don't have any Master/Critical tables with fields of data type blob.

Comment: @EdMendez sometimes blobs can be created even without having those as fields, for example the `LIST` aggr-funciton in Firebird 2.1. Now, those temporary blobs are expected to be deleted on transaction closing, but if you don't do (spaghetti code with broken tx management, or once popular "eternal read-only transaction" mode) - then those temp blobs are never deleted until app disconnect (which finally closes TXs) and the growth can be real fast.